# No recorro bien el array y no sé cual es el problema

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio que dice así:

> Crea un algoritmo que nos muestre una secuencia cíclica de las
> palabras Perro Gato Lobo hasta alcanzar el número de palabras que
> elija el usuario. Ejemplo: si se solicitan 7 palabras la serie será:
> Perro, Gato, Lobo, Perro, Gato, Lobo, Perro.

Mi código es este:

```
package ejercicios2pdf;

import utilidades.Entrada;

/*
 * Crea un algoritmo que nos muestre una secuencia cíclica de las palabras Perro Gato Lobo hasta alcanzar el número de
palabras que elija el usuario.
Ejemplo: si se solicitan 7 palabras la serie será: Perro, Gato, Lobo, Perro, Gato, Lobo, Perro.
 * */
public class P17_SecuenciaCiclica {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int cnt=0;
        int i=0;
        boolean salida=false;
        String [] al = new String [3];
        
        al[0]="Perro";
        al[1]="Gato";
        al[2]="Lobo";
        
        System.out.println("Palabras solicitadas ");
        int numpal=Entrada.entero();
        

        do {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
    
            if (i==3) {
            
                i=0;
                System.out.println(al[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.println(al[i]);
                i++;
        
            }

            cnt++;
        } while (numpal != cnt);
    
    }

}
```

La cosa es que cuando yo le solicito 7, me da este resultado:

0 Perro
1 Gato
2 Lobo
3 Perro
0 Perro
1 Gato
2 Lobo

Se repite de nuevo "Perro" en vez de seguir con "Gato".

¿Qué es lo que falla?

Answer (score 2):

Lo arreglé:

```
do {
        System.out.print(i+" ");

        if (i>=2) {
            System.out.println(al[i]);

            i=0;
    
        } else {
            System.out.println(al[i]);
            i++;
        
        }

        cnt++;
    } while (numpal != cnt);
```

El problema era que el syso de cuando es i==3 estaba despues de i==0 por lo tanto nunca escribe el tercero ya que lo convierte a i==0, y por tanto en vez de i==3 tiene que ser i>=2 ya que si no, se saldría del array y no se podría resolver